# Regular Expression for IFSC Code of Indian Bank

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

The IFSC code is consists of first 4 letters then '0' then 6 digits. The Regex is below
    [A-Z|a-z]{4}[0][\d]{6}$
But i am using OCR to extract text so i am cleaning the code

```
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace(",","")
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace("X","0")
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace("o","0")
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace("O","0")
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace("(","")
        ifsc_code = ifsc_code.replace(")","")
```

so what it does it converts "ORBC0101346" to "0RBC0101346" and my regex fails.
what i was thinking to do is to split this ifsc code into 2 parts firsts 4 characters and do the cleaning and then the second part consisting of numbers only and then join them together at the end after cleaning.

Comment: Why not just `[A-Za-z0]{4}0\d{6}$` ? - So allow zeros in addition to letters in the first part?

Comment: then doing this :
                    if ifsc_code[0] == "0":
                        ifsc_code = "O" + ifsc_code[1:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing on my comment: You could use match groups to peel the different components apart, such as

```
def parse_ifsc(ifsc_code):
    m = re.match('([A-Za-z0]{4})(0\d{6})$', ifsc_code)
    if m:
        return m.group(1).replace('0', 'O').upper() + m.group(2)
    else:
        return None
```

Answer (score 1):

The above-mentioned regex `([A-Za-z0]{4})(0\d{6})$` is not correct. That's because it works with all the Indian banks *except* "Bank of Borada" eg. BARB0DAWARK - it fails

So the correct regex is:

```
/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{1}[A-Z0-9]{6}$/
```

It matches all the Indian IFSC codes.